# Angular 8 - Building with IVY - how to interpret the error messages

Tags: angular-ivy

Currently I am moving an Angular 7 project (monorepo using NX) with libs (mostly without npm packaging) to Angular 8 and - after running a successful build - would like to activate IVY for the build.

The errors written out to the console

```
E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120>npm run deploy

> oxs-repo@0.0.0 deploy E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120
> node -v && npm -version && ng build client-oxseco --configuration=docker --base-href=/

v10.16.3
6.13.4
11% building 10/11 modules 1 active ...yre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\postcss-loader
11% building 10/12 modules 2 active ...?extracted!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules
\sass-loader\lib\loader.js??ref--15-3!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\apps\client\oxseco\src\s
11% building 10/13 modules 3 active ...EV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loa
der.js??ref--15-3!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\libs\config-app\feature-config-app\src\lib\s
11% building 10/14 modules 4 active ...yre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\sass-loader\li
b\loader.js??ref--15-3!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\libs\shared\auth\feature-auth\src\lib\s
11% building 11/14 modules 3 active ...EV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js??ref--15-3!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend
11% building 11/15 modules 4 active ...e_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js??ref--15-3!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-front
11% building 12/15 modules 3 active ...EV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js??ref--15-3!E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend

ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at skipSynthesizedParentheses (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:93294:25)
    at needsIndentation (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:93279:21)
    at emitBinaryExpression (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:91656:39)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:90939:32)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:93731:17)
    at pipelineEmit (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:90537:13)
    at emitExpression (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:90529:20)
    at emitExpressionStatement (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:91757:13)
    at pipelineEmitWithHint (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:90728:32)
    at pipelineEmitWithComments (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:93731:17)
    at pipelineEmit (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:90537:13)
    at emit (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:90517:30)
    at emitNodeList (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:93047:21)
    at emitList (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:92919:13)
    at emitBlockStatements (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:91738:13)
    at emitBlock (E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:91733:13)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! oxs-repo@0.0.0 deploy: `node -v && npm -version && ng build client-oxseco --configuration=docker --base-href=/ `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oxs-repo@0.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Valerie\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-22T11_40_16_184Z-debug.log

E:\Nyre_DEV_Work\oxs-frontend.20200120>
```

**Question - what do these errors indicate?**